# SQL Left Join returning NULL value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a databse with tables `schedule` and a table `teams` (as can be seen in image below) Im trying to use the `homeID` & `awayID` inside the the `schedule` table to do a join on the `teams` table....Problem is it is returning NULL

**DB Layout**

[image]

**`Schedule` Table Layout**

[image]

**`teams` table layout**

[image]

**My Query**

```
SELECT s.*,
  t1.teamId as homeId_teamId,
  t1.teamCode as homeId_teamCode,
  t1.teamName as homeId_teamName,
  t2.teamId as visitorId_teamId,
  t2.teamCode as visitorId_teamCode,
  t2.teamName as visitorId_teamName
FROM schedule s
  LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON s.homeId = t1.teamName
  LEFT JOIN teams t2 ON s.visitorId = t2.teamName
WHERE  gameID = '1';
```

**Returned Result**

[image]

Any idea why am I getting a NULL value for the join? What am I missing here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want home**Id** and visitor**Id** to team**Name**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`s should be joined to `id`s (not names):

```
SELECT s.*,
      t1.teamId as homeId_teamId,
      t1.teamCode as homeId_teamCode,
      t1.teamName as homeId_teamName,
      t2.teamId as visitorId_teamId,
      t2.teamCode as visitorId_teamCode,
      t2.teamName as visitorId_teamName
FROM schedule s LEFT JOIN
     teams t1
     ON s.homeId = t1.teamId LEFT JOIN
     teams t2
     ON s.visitorId = t2.teamId
WHERE s.gameID = 1;
```

`gameID` is an integer, so the comparison should be to a number, not a string.

I note that the tpes of `homeId` and `visitorId` don't match `teams.teamId`, but naming suggests that this is the right condition.  If foreign keys were properly defined, then the types would have to match.

Comment: One of those where you bang your head against the wall and say DOH! I just wasted an hour of my life. Thank you so much! Will except when time expires

Comment: Note, `homeId` is `varchar(20)`, but `teamId` is `int`.

Comment: @Alexander yeah the DB was poorly designed. Thanks for pointing that out. It used to contain team name before a new table `teams` was created.